# create stacked graph with subcategories

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm trying to create a stacked bar graph in excel with more than just simple series.

What I have:
company name, product name, product market share per year (2013,2014,2015).

On the vertical side 'Y', there should be the value meter and on the horizontal side 'X', the year grouped by company.

Do for example:

```
 - SONY
      - 2013
            - TV
            - Walkman
            - CDs
      - 2014
            - TV
            - Walkman
            - CDs
 - SAMSUNG
      - 2013
            - Phone
            - Tablets
            - Computer
            - Laptops
            - Other
      - 2014
            - Phone
            - Tablets
            - Computer
            - Laptops
            - Other
```

I think I'm not using the right keywords on google to find a tutorial. Any help would be appreciated, an example file would be even better to understand it for my future needs.

[image: Illustration of the result]

Comment: Welcome to Super User. New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Hi, sorry I'm exhausted after hours of trying. I'm new on super user but not on stack exchange ;) I'm not asking for someone to do the work but to point me in the right direction. From what I know that's quite the objective of this community right ?

Comment: We understand. Simply explain what you have tried and what the results are. We will try to help you figure it out, but we are not here to teach you how. From your example, what is the data that the graph is based off of since there are no values?

Comment: So each bar is a manufacturer/year and the segments are product types?  The data is something like sales dollars for each product type?  What does the source data look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are after is a stacked clustered column chart. Jon Peltier has a tutorial on his web site here:

[image]

http://peltiertech.com/clustered-stacked-column-bar-charts/

It requires some careful arrangement of the chart source data and some clever techniques to place and hide chart elements.